# Spring Integration File synchronizer : Accept files based on a pre defined list

Tags: spring, spring-integration, filtering, spring-integration-sftp

I am transfering files from a remote to a local by Sftp, for processing.
I want to only transfer .csv files, and I have a list of pre-defined filenames.

I couldn't find a FileListFilter that allows to specify multiple patterns and transfer if at least one if matched.

So far I have this code, that's woorking for ".csv" filtering.

The Integration Flow

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(ftpMessageSource(), c -> poller())
            ... more processing
```

The MessageSource

```
public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {

            SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sessionFactory);
            fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
            fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
            fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(Constantes.EXTENSION));
            SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource ftpInboundFileSync = 
                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(fileSynchronizer);

            ftpInboundFileSync.setLocalDirectory(new File(workDirectory));
            ftpInboundFileSync.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
            CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
            compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(Constantes.EXTENSION));
            ftpInboundFileSync.setLocalFilter(compositeFileListFilter);
            return ftpInboundFileSync;
    }
```

Constantes.EXTENSION is a regex accepting .csv and .CSV. This works fine.

Say that I have a String list that contains "string1',"string2","string3" and I want to transfer every file of the form string1*, string2* or string3*. How would I proceed ?

Comment: One solution would be to set up an ungly Regex that checks for each one of my filenames ? There is 7 items in this list as of today, that won't change much in the future. But I would rather avoid doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So59161698Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59161698Application.class, args);
    }

    private final String myPatterns = "foo,bar,baz";

    @Bean
    public FileListFilter<File> filter() {
        Set<String> patterns = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(this.myPatterns);
        return files -> Arrays.stream(files)
                .filter(file -> patterns.stream()
                        .filter(pattern -> file.getName().startsWith(pattern))
                        .findFirst()
                        .isPresent())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(FileListFilter<File> filter) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(filter.filterFiles(new File[] {
                    new File("foo.csv"),
                    new File("bar.csv"),
                    new File("baz.csv"),
                    new File("qux.csv")
            }));
        };
    }

}
```

```
[foo.csv, bar.csv, baz.csv]
```

Comment: Looks exactly like what I need, and simple implementation with base FileListFilter. I will try this at work tomorrow and update accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There is a `CompositeFileListFilter`:

```
* Simple {@link FileListFilter} that predicates its matches against <b>all</b> of the
* configured {@link FileListFilter}.
```

With the logic like:

```
public boolean accept(F file) {
    AtomicBoolean allAccept = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    // we can't use stream().allMatch() because we have to call all filters for this filter's contract
    this.fileFilters.forEach(f -> allAccept.compareAndSet(true, f.accept(file)));
    return allAccept.get();
}
```

So, you configure this `CompositeFileListFilter` with several `SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter` delegates and your files are going to be processed whenever they much at least one of the filters in the `CompositeFileListFilter`.

See more about filters in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-reading